# Slav - Theory Heavy Book

Tags: opening, theory, books, slav-defense

I have come to the realization that studying opening theory is far and away my favorite aspect of chess.

That being said I am looking for a comprehensive theory heavy book on the Slav. I would like one that deals with pawn structure formations, middle game plans, and potentially end games that occur frequently. I would also like one that deals with the subtleties of move order as sometimes that is glossed over in books that are rushed to be published. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Looking for something aimed at the 2000+ level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/Grandmaster-Repertoire-17-Classical-Slav/dp/1907982388](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1907982388)

Grandmaster Repertoire 17 by Avrukh is probably what you're looking for. It is extremely dense and detailed. It will require a lot of work to get all the information that you need, but there are a lot of rewards there as well.

If you have not studied that Slav before, I would recommend:

[http://www.amazon.com/Slav-Move-Everyman-Chess/dp/185744678X/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1347014456&sr=1-2&keywords=slav+defence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/185744678X)

Slav: Move by Move by Lakdawala as it gives a great overview of the plans and ideas of the opening and provides puzzles and quizzes throughout the games to test your understanding.

The Slav is a great opening and I wish you luck in your studies!

Comment: +1 I agree that the Lakdawala book is very good (I enjoy and recommend it myself), but the author is selective in his coverage, as he says himself in the text, so I'm not sure I would call it complete, as is requested by the OP.

Comment: I'll agree that it's not a full coverage of the opening, but I feel that is a good thing. Trying to be too comprehensive can easily dilute content as the Slav is a very complex opening at the higher levels.

Answer (score 1):

The Encyclopaedia of Chess Openings,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_of_Chess_Openings

was (is?) one of the earliest comprehensive theory books when I studied chess in my early days. It seems that these books are still published and updated:

http://www.chessinformant.org/eco-encyclopedia-of-chess-openings

However the analyses in the book might not fully cover all the aspects you are asking for. The included analyses might take you in the right direction though..

Answer (score 0):

Another complete, theory heavy and high quality work on the Slav Defence is "The Complete Slav" by GM Konstantin Sakaev. This series consists of two books, [Volume I](https://www.newinchess.com/complete-slav-i) and [Volume II](https://www.newinchess.com/complete-slav-ii), published in 2012 and 2013 respectively.